# Is there a way copy and paste the text information in winver.exe?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, version

I'm reporting a software error with the platform information which is provided in in Winver.exe.

But I can't highlight the text and copy it (this is in Windows XP SP2).

Is there a registry key or somewhere else I can grab the build info?
I've tried PsInfo from Sysinternals but it doesn't provide all the build and sp info.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want the OS info, you can run all sorts of commands from the command line:
WMIC has many :

```
WMIC OS Get Name
```

Returns:

```
Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise |C:\Windows|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition2
```

You can also use

```
wmic OS get /?
```

to get all your choices for that WMIC class.

```
systeminfo | Findstr /i "OS"
```

Will get you:

> Host Name:                 MYCOMPUTERNAME OS Name:
>   Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise OS Version:                6.1.7601
>   Service Pack 1 Build 7601 OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft
>   Corporation OS Configuration:          Member Workstation OS Build
>   Type:             Multiprocessor Free BIOS Version:              Dell
>   Inc. A08, 10/18/2011
>                              [04]: Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter

You can then either pipe this to text, or copy from the command line as I did above.

Another attempt to get the what appears to be service pack information:

Run:

```
wmic os get * /value > C:\WMICOS.txt
```

the search that file for the string you want.

Comment: All of these provide some of the info, but not all.  In XP there is a specific term after the build# ending in _rtm.040803-2158 that is not in any of the above.  Thanks for the info, though, learnt something new.

Comment: @MandoMando added another suggestion to the end

Comment: @MandoMando: The build number's what's really important. The build date and time (i.e. August 3, 2004 @ 9:58PM) should be same for all copies of the SP2 RTM release, so unless you have some sort of leaked release there's no point bothering too much about it.

Answer (score 0):

A handy but ill-documented feature in most versions of Windows is that pressing Ctrl-c while the focus is on a dialog will copy the text in the dialog. I'm not sure whether it works with the dialog produced by `winver.exe`, but I would be surprised if it didn't; try hitting Ctrl-c in that dialog and then Ctrl-v in a Notepad window, and see what you get.

**UPDATE** Color me surprised; it doesn't work. Good job, Microsoft!

Comment: Lol and `winver` executed from the command line logs nothing but opens a gui dialog..... Now why oh why dear MS would we be executing the command from the command line if we didn't want the output to go there as well?